# How many points are necessary to calculate $\int_2^6\ln(x)dx$ using Simpson's rule with error $\le 5*10^{-4}$?

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus, simpsons-rule

How many points of integration are necessary to calculate the integral

$$\int_2^6\ln(x)dx$$

using Simpson's rule such that the absolute error of integration is lesser or equal to $5*10^{-4}$, knowing that the values for $\ln(x)$ have 7 significant digits?

$$E(f) = -\frac{h^4(b-a)}{180}f^{(4)}(\eta)$$
$$h = \frac{b-a}{N}$$
where N = number of intervals in between points, which should me even for Simpson's Rule.

---

What I tried to do:

$$h = \frac{6-2}{N} = 4/N \\
E(f) = -\frac{4^5}{N^4}*1/180*f^{(4)}(\eta) \\
f^{(4)} = -6x^{-4} \\
|E(f)| \le 5*10^{-4} \Leftrightarrow \\
|\frac{4^5}{180N^4}|\max_{6,2}|-6x^{-4}| \le 5*10^{-4} \Leftrightarrow \\
N = 0.12374 \approx 1$$

This solution doesn't make a whole lot of sense. Help?

Comment: That last line makes no sense, it should not be an equation, it should be an inequality. Starting from the inequality
$$N^4 \ge \frac{4^5}{5 \cdot 10^{-4} \cdot 180} \cdot \max_{x \in [2,6]} \left| -6 x^{-4} \right|
$$
and then doing some arithmetic, the result should be an inequality of the form
$$N \ge \text{SOMETHING}
$$

Comment: When I do your calculation, I get $N$ to be a little more than $8$.

Comment: @B.Goddard is that the answer then? What about that stuff with the significant digits of ln(x)?

Comment: If my calculation is right, then $N>8$, so for Simpson's rule, that would force $N=10$.    So you'll have to compute 11 natural logs.  Each one might have an error as big as $5\times 10^{-7}$, so you need to add up that potential error and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: @B.Goddard by applying the formula for the propagation of error to Simpson's rule?

Comment: I think I'd just brute-force it.  Figure out how much those tiny errors could add up to and see whether they matter.

Comment: @B.Goddard ok but how?